# Product of complex Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices equals zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices, and they can be diagonalized as $A=U_{A}{\lambda}_{A} U_{A}^{H}$ and $B=U_{B}{\lambda}_{B} U_{B}^{H}$. Then whether $AB=0$ implies ${\lambda}_{A}{\lambda}_{B}=0$? If not, please give a counterexample.

Comment: More accurately, $\lambda_{A}$ and $\lambda_{B}$ are in reverse order, i.e., the diagonal entries of $\lambda_{A}$ are in nonincreasing order and the diagonal entries of $\lambda_{B}$ are in nondecreasing order, and $tr\{A\}=tr\{B\}$, is the original problem true?

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\\\
1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\qquad
B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\\\
-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$\lambda_A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\\\
0 & 0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
\lambda_B = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\\\
0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

$$AB=0, \lambda_A\lambda_B \neq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=I\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}I$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB=0$ but $\lambda_A=\lambda_B=\lambda_A\lambda_B=A\not=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In this generality, it's not true. For a counterexample, let
$$A:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\ B:=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}\,,$$
and $U_A:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, $\ U_B:=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$. Then $\lambda_A=\lambda_B=A$, and $AB=0$ but $\lambda_A\lambda_B=A^2=A\ne 0$.